# Generate all subsequences of length m from a character array of length n where n >= m in Java language

Tags: java, subsequence

I was looking for an optimal code in Java for generating all subsequences of length m from a character array of length n, where n >= m.

The meaning of subsequence is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence

My current psuedocode/algorithm is below. But it doesn't look optimized.

```
if (m <= 0)
    return;
for (i = 0; i < 2^n; i++) { // can use BigInteger if n > 64
    j = numberOfBitsSet(i); // assuming numberOfBitsSet is implemented
    if (j == m) {
        s = "";
        while((index = getIndexOfNextBitSet(i)) >= 0) { // assuming getIndexOfNextBitSet is implemented
            s = s + charArray[index]; // bit numbering starts from zero
        } // end of while
        System.out.println(s);
    } // end of if
} // end of for
```

Comment: can you please explain what you mean? From what i read i understand you have a char array for example 'h','e','l','l','o' and you want to generate all subsequenses of length m. What would be the result here lets say for subsequence length=2

Comment: The result would be: he, hl, hl, ho, el, el, eo, ll, lo, lo

Comment: `can use BigInteger if n > 64` as well as the number of outputted subsequences, meaning  you can not do that realistically, neither you can optimise any further.

Comment: Boris, I did not completely understand your comment. But I am looking for a different algorithm than mine which is optimized.

Comment: Boris, I did not completely understand your comment. But I am looking for a different algorithm than mine. Also, looking for an optimized algorithm.

Comment: Do you need to output all subsequences? If yes, the number of subsequences itself is a strict bound for your complexity.

Comment: I need to output only those subsequences whose length is m.

Comment: Does your  code work? Is this an assignment?

Comment: It is psuedocode. I haven't run it. This is not an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I solve algorithmic tasks in C++. There is the cool function of `next_permutation` that allows you to shuffle through all "permutations" of a sequence. If the sequence is say "00110100" `next_permutation` will give you "00111000" (in optimal way).

I found an example implementation of the same function in java [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-next_permutation-in-java-with-examples/).

How this can help you solve your problem: initialize a sequence with `n`-`m` leading zeroes followed by `m` ones. Use your mask-base generation. After that do `next_permutation`. The complexity of this algorithm is `n`* `subsequence_count`. This will be significant improvement if you know that `m` follows certain rules, but once again will trigger huge number of results if n = 64 and m = 32 for example.

Comment: Yeah, this looks optimized. Basically, it boils down to generating all permutations of a character array where m indices are set to 1. And to generate all permutations we don't need integer loop, it can be done recursively using character array. But obviously, we need to take care of duplicates.

Comment: @Amit actually i just visualized the idea in a string, but `next_permutation` algorithm works on any kind of array. I would rather use array of integers. `next_permutation` algorithm itself takes care of not repeating any "permutation" (e.g. 0111001 will not appear multiple times). If by duplicates you mean not printing "hl" multiple times in your example, I thought this is desired effect.

Comment: I meant duplicate permutations. Printing "hl" multiple times is okay. But if n = 1,000,000 and m = 500,000 then we will have to go for string (character array).

Comment: @Amit I meant that you can have `int [] bitset = new int[n];` holding if the particular bit is set or not. You can initialize it to `m` trailing ones and iterate over its permutations. With this approach you do not need to be limited by primary types max bounds.